# DjangoRestFramework group objects by a field in the object?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How can objects be grouped by a field in the object, such that all objects with the same value of that field are under one folder/layer/bracket of the JSON?

For example, change from this:

```
{
    "foo" : [
        {
            "type" : "letter",
            "value" : "x"
        },
        {
            "type" : "letter",
            "value" : "y"
        },
        {
            "type" : "letter",
            "value" : "z"
        },
        {
            "type" : "number",
            "value" : "1"
        },
        {
            "type" : "number",
            "value" : "0"
        }
    ]
}
```

To this:

```
{
    "bar" : {
        "letter" : ["x", "y", "z"],
        "number" : ["1", "0"]
    }
}
```

---

For context, here is some of my code boiled down to the relevant parts:

```
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    type = serializers.CharField(source='type.type')

    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ('tag', 'type')

class Tag(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey('TagType', models.CASCADE, 'tags')
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=254, unique=True)

class TagType(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=254, unique=True)
```

In pseudocode, this is what I think would be the first step to accomplishing this. How can this be implemented with or without DRF? Where do I put it?

```
def TagTypeSerializer():
    types = TagType.objects.all()
    json = []
    for t in types:
        json += t.type
    return json
```

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure this is achievable thru Django's REST F itself, maybe some javascript on the template?

Comment: Is there some way to do it outside DRF but still on backend?

Comment: I'd recommend you to go clientside with JS

Comment: Is that just because doing it this way is too difficult? Or some other reasons?

Comment: It is way difficult for my taste, but let's see if somebody comes up with another idea though :)

Comment: Show us your `ViewSet` please.

Comment: @AlexMorozov The viewset is a simple generics.ListAPIView with Tag.objects.all()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it's possible, you'll have to completely override the `list()` method of your view:

```
class ListTags(generics.ListAPIView):
    def transform_result(self, data):
        """Your custom data transformations"""
        result = {'tags': set(), 'types': set()}
        for tag in data:
            result['tags'].update(data['tag'])
            result['types'].update(data['type'])
        return result

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(self.transform_result(serializer.data))

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(self.transform_result(serializer.data))
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the most natural way to do it. I wonder if `transform_result` will take significantly more time compared to just returning `Response(serializer.data)`, will have to profile that to see.

Comment: It depends on the count of objects in your queryset, but I doubt it cause any slowdown compared to `ModelSerializer` itself. Simply put, it's just a single loop.

Answer (score -2):

Django REST framework serializers don't work like that.
You'll likely want to roll your own class to serialize / deserialize.

Comment: I've added an edit at the bottom of my OP, could you please take a look and tell me how I can make that work?